# How can I split a text file into multiple files based on start of line patterns?

Tags: shell, text-processing, awk, macos

I have text files which I'd like to divide up into different files based on arbitrary "tags" I put at the start of various lines.

Example text file:

```bsh
I CELEBRATE myself, and sing myself,  
And what I assume you shall assume, 
For every atom belonging to me as good belongs to you.

#here I loafe and invite my soul, 
#here I lean and loafe at my ease observing a spear of summer grass.

#there My tongue, every atom of my blood, form'd from this soil, this air,
#there Born here of parents born here from parents the same, and their parents the same, 
#here I, now thirty-seven years old in perfect health begin, 
#here Hoping to cease not till death.
```

In this example I'd like to remove every line beginning with `#here` and append it onto a file called `here.txt`, every line beginning with `#there` into a file called `there.txt`, and leave every untagged line in the original file. (Ideally removing the `#here` `#there` tags in the process.)

I think this solution using `awk` might be helpful, but I am such a Unix noob that I don't know how to adapt this to my problem: [How to split a file by using keyword boundaries](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76929/how-to-split-a-file-by-using-keyword-boundaries)

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

PS: I'm using the command line on OS X.

Comment: Do you **only** want to put `#here` lines into `here.txt` and `#there` lines into `there.txt` (so a line starting with `#elsewhere`, for example, would remain untouched) or do you just want to put `#tag` lines into `tag.txt` for all `tag`s found in the input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your case is simpler than the linked case - you only need to look at each line (or "record" in awk parlance) and decide where to send it. So:

```
awk '/^#here/{print > "here.txt"; next} /^#there/{print > "there.txt"; next} {print}' input.txt
```

The remaining lines will be printed to standard output; portably, you can redirect that to a third file (`rest.txt` say) then rename it to the name of the original. If you have GNU awk, you can use the `inplace` module to modify the original file directly:

```
gawk -i inplace '/^#here/{print > "here.txt"; next} /^#there/{print > "there.txt"; next} {print}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed` `w` command:

```
sed -n -e '/^#here/w here.txt' -e '/^#there/w there.txt' data
```

To preserve the row which not begin with the desired pattern:

```
sed -n -e '/^#here/w here.txt' -e '/^#there/w there.txt' -e '/^$/d;' -e '/^#/!w new_data.txt' data
```

This `sed` apply a match to the line and write it to the corresponding file.

If the line is untagged (`/^#/!`), and it is not empty(`/^$/`), then write the line to a file called `new_data.txt`, the file with all the untagged row.

If you like to keep the empty line remove the `-e /^$/d;` from the command line.